# Exact algorithm to fit bags in python

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a set of items which have a `size` property.

I also have a set of bags which can contain `number` items. Each item must be in the interval of `min_size` and `max_size`. For simplification, we can also consider we have only have bags of one item within min and max size.

Given these two sets, I must determine if I can fit the items in the bags, within limited time complexity.

This looks like a knapsack problem, but it differs from it slightly from some points and may be solved more efficiently from ways I am not aware of.

Right now, my attempt is to make a first-fit-decreasing but it is not correct in all cases and I must implement an exact approach.

Does anyone have an efficient solution for this problem ? This is a general, language agnostic question but examples in Python are prefered.

Comment: A question about the bag specification: Is a bag _only_ constrained by `number` and `min_size` and `max_size`? So, if a bag can contain 2 items, could those items both be of `min_size`, or both be of `max_size`, or one of each, or even just some sizes inbetween? Or is the bag specification more specific?

Comment: @Hans the bag is only constrained by these numbers, and a bag can contain 0, 1 or two items each item size being between min_size and max_size. So it can contain two items of size max, two of size min, two inbetween, one min one max...

Comment: One way to go is to see this as a graph problem: A bag with `number` capacity is the same as `number` bags with a single-item capacity each (with the same `min` and `max`). You then get a bipartite graph of item nodes on the one side, and bag nodes on the other, where each bag is connected to all items it could contain given the size constraints. This can solved as a maximum flow problem in `O(|items| * |single-capacity bags|)`. There are some nice slides about it here: http://ac.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws14_15/algo1415/pdf/05_GraphAlgorithms_p5.pdf

Comment: @Hans Thanks for your comment ! I didn't think of transposing it into graphs.